# Please help me how to make a truth table from an boolean expression

Tags: education, boolean-algebra, math-software, regular-expressions

**I am trying to make a truth table from an SOP boolean algebra expression**
This is the expression:
$((A+B) \oplus C')' + AB'$

Comment: @TahirAli For future questions use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: mathjax uses \lor \land \lnot \oplus

Answer (score 1):

Decompose the expression to make one operation at a time, then fill the table.

$\begin{array}{|ccc|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & B & C & d=\lnot B & e=\lnot C & f=A\lor B & g=f\oplus e & h=\lnot g & i=A\land d & h\lor i\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
1 & 0 & 0 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
0 & 1 & 1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
0 & 1 & 0 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
0 & 0 & 1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}$

I've done some, I let you complete the rest.